# Нетрадиционный TypeScript или js + d.ts как основной способ разработки

Tags: javascript, typescript

Задавал уже этот вопрос на английском - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72579249/use-typescript-declaration-in-corresponding-javascript-file. Ответа так и не дождался.

В общем, суть в том, что я хочу использовать TypeScript, но при этом хочу писать непосредственно рабочий код на чистом JavaScript, без какой-либо компиляции. Идея в том, чтобы для каждого js файла создавать d.ts. Идея как бы не нова, но суть в том, что d.ts изначально, насколько я понял, предназначен для добавления типов в уже существующие библиотеки, чтобы те могли нормально работать с использующим их кодом на тайпскрипте. Я же хотел бы видеть полноценную проверку js с помощью d.ts.

То есть, что я имею ввиду. Файл js, к которому прикреплен d.ts, должен проверятся так, будто это ts файл, как бы сумма этих двух файлов. Если, предположим, js экспортирует функцию, а в d.ts описан тип возвращаемого ей значения, то должна быть проверка, действительно ли функция возвращает подобное значение. Ну и что входные данные, допустим, те же аргументы функции, используются правильно - тоже должно проверятся.

То есть, например:

```typescript
// a.d.ts
export function a(val: string): string;
```

```js
// a.js
// Правильная реализация
export function a(val) {
    return `Hello ${val}`;
}
```

```js
// a.js
// Здесь две ошибки:
// аргумент является строкой, а строки не имеют метода "toFixed",
// и возвращаемый тип в любом случае не является строкой
export function a(val) {
    return {val: val.toFixed()};
}
```

Документацию тайпскрипта я прошерстил от и до, и не нашел, как сделать подобную штуку. Флаг `checkJs` - максимум, на что тайпскрипт способен, но это всего лишь проверка корректного использования других модулей, а не реализации самого js модуля на основе своего d.ts. И он становится достаточно бесполезным, когда имеется зависимость от принимаемых на вход, а не создаваемых прямо внутри значений, ведь банально становится неизвестным тип этих самых значений. Поля класса всегда `any`, методы всегда принимают `any` и возвращают `any` - толку от тайпскрипта в таком случае никакого...

Ожидаемо, тайпскрипт не предполагает подобных извращений. Но, может быть, есть какое-то решение? Какая-нибудь библиотека, плагин, что угодно, что помогло бы добиться описанного результата?

Comment: Я перешёл на JSDoc, очень удобная и классная штука, особенно с поддержкой IDE WEBStorm :) Там есть всё что надо, типы, интерфейсы, абстрактные классы, проверка типов (подсвечивает или выделяет, если что-то не так), generic types и многое другое :)

Comment: @EzioMercer Я тоже раньше использовал JSDoc, и сейчас для тайпскрипта использую TypeDoc. И даже без IDE тайпскрипт с `checkJs` поддерживает более-менее оба формата. Но вот интересный факт: до начала использования TypeScript я писал JSDoc в отдельном от js-реализации файле. Я в принципе сторонник идеи разделения штук с разным назначением по разным файлам. И это основная причина, по которой я предпочитаю js + d.ts, нежели ts. Проблема компиляции достаточно второстепенна.

Comment: Ну, на вкус и цвет как говорится :) Я объявления в другие файлы выношу только тогда когда это используется в 2-х или более местах. А так люблю когда всё перед глазами и не надо отдельно смотреть на реализацию и на объявление типов

Comment: @EzioMercer Меня наоборот сбивает, когда вместе с кодом, который отвечает за непосредственно работу приложения, располагается нечто, что этот код описывает. Удобнее и быстрее прочесть чисто интерфейс, когда нужно знать, как использовать модуль, и чисто реализацию, чтобы понять, как оно устроено внутри. Но, опять же, на вкус и цвет...